# Code translation VB to C# in a Sync Framework 2.1 sample

Tags: c#, vb.net, microsoft-sync-framework, code-translation

I followed a walkthrough of a sync framework 2.1 sample and it works fine. But it's written in C# and I want to port it to VB. I came to the following line which I have had a hard time translating:

in the static Main of c#:

```
((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);
```

later on there is a handler written as:

```
 static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        // display conflict type
        Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.Type);

        // display error message 
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
    }
```

how should I translate the first line to VB?

I tried the auto translators which give me two results (both fail to compile)

```
AddHandler CType(syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider,SqlSyncProvider).ApplyChangeFailed, AddressOf Me.Program_ApplyChangeFailed
```

and

```
DirectCast(syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider, SqlSyncProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += New EventHandler(Of DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs)(Program_ApplyChangeFailed)
```

Comment: What part did the dozens of c# to vb code converters on google failed to translate for you?

Comment: It's the first thing I tried. It translates to: DirectCast(syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider, SqlSyncProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += New EventHandler(Of DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs)(Program_ApplyChangeFailed) But that gives an error.

Comment: What was the error? The AddHandler / AdressOf method should be working.

Comment: The conversion using DirectCast and leaving the "+=" operator in is definitely wrong - the first one using AddHandler looks perfect. What is the compile error?

Comment: OK yes finally got it to work with: AddHandler CType(syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider, SqlSyncProvider).ApplyChangeFailed, AddressOf Program_ApplyChangeFailed
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work with:

```
AddHandler CType(syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider, SqlSyncProvider).ApplyChangeFailed, AddressOf Program_ApplyChangeFailed
```